Vastly different build times
I have a .NET 7 Blazor web assembly application. When building the solution, it can vary from about 20 seconds to about 2 minutes. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to go about diagnosing why?
A few notes:

I have a 13th gen I9 paired with 32GB of ram -- resources should not be an issue

I have very little installed on the laptop -- Visual Studio/SQL Server, SSMS, MS Office

I typically have very little running besides Visual Studio, MS Edge, and maybe SSMS

I have only had the laptop for about a month, it is fairly clean

Using Task Manager, I see cpu/memory at about 15%/60% usage, with a quick cpu spike% and then dropping back down to the 20% range (although right now, it is compiling in about 30 seconds) - when it is compiling slowly and I have checked Task Manager, I believe it has been comparable.


Any guidance on how to diagnose this?


There's better forums for these types of questions, but one of the big culprits in situations like this is AV.

.NET 7 reached end of life a while ago, so others might not be able to reproduce this. If you want to investigate further, then 1) try to see if .NET 8 has the same issue,  and 2) enable MSBuild bin log to see into the differences, https://msbuildlog.com/

Thanks to you both.
Lex:  Do you have a recommendation on a forum for this type of question?
Lex Li:  My intent is to upgrade to .NET 8 but hoping to push that back about 2 months.  I will look into the MS Build Bin Log.

You may get more/better responses on the Superuser forum. There may even be a better SO site, you can check them out here: https://stackexchange.com/sites.

Thank you Lex.  I have not seen that and will check it out.
